# My App Keeps Getting Crash Because of This Code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-sheets

I am Trying to Connect google sheets with android app and my app keeps crashing every time this code executes

```
   button5.setOnClickListener {
      val HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
        val spreadsheetId = "MYSHEET_ID"
        val range = "Users!A1"
        val service =
            Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build()
        val response: ValueRange = service.spreadsheets().values()[spreadsheetId, range]
            .execute()
        val values: List<List<Any>> = response.getValues()

       Toast.makeText(this, values[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
```

i took this code from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java?hl=ja

EDIT: So i just found out the problem is in `val HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()` This Line

EDIT 2: the error/exception i get here is "java.security.KeyStoreException: 
JKS not found

Comment: Are you seeing any error message? If so, could you please include?

Comment: @lordoku i just did idk how i forgot to add that

Comment: Looks like you don't have a Keystore setup. I'd check the Google documentation on how to set it up. I'll see if I can find anything and will post if I find something.

Comment: Ok the link to the question is out of date. I'm still looking.

Comment: Did you follow the setup steps: 
1) Enable the Google Sheets API
2) Copy the credentials.json file you downloaded in Step 1 into the src/main/resources/ directory you just created.
3) Include all of the dependencies?

Here's the link I was following: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java

Comment: yes i did do that but as the example code is given in java and i need to use that in android after converting it in kotlin i downloaded it in app/java/com.xxxxxx.xxxx Here https://imgur.com/a/5aV1XHU